# How To Remove Rails Installation From /usr/bin/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on MacOS Mojave. Here's what I have so far:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]

rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

which rails
usr/bin/rails
```

I've done some research on the issue and it looks like because I used `sudo` when I originally ran `gem install rails`, the rails executable got put in a location where it doesn't have access to the right libraries.

How do I fix this or remove the rails executable to start a fresh install from scratch?

Comment: `uninstall`? You need to be careful mucking about with OS X's Ruby and gems since it's used by the system, though.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that rails isn't part of OS X's core files. I disabled SIP and removed the rails install at /usr/bin/rails. When I run `which rails` it returns nothing. `rails -v` returns `-bash: rails: command not found`. I already ran `gem install rails` and `rbenv rehash` and restarted the terminal. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the existing Rails installation in your system Ruby. Don't bother mucking about with any changes you've made to system Ruby and its gems. Just put it in the past and move on:

Install RVM with:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Restart your shell, then install Ruby with:

```
rvm install 2.6.5
```

[Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Then install Rails (without `sudo`, never use `sudo` with Ruby installed by RVM):

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: This says what to do the *next* time (although OP specifically tags with `rbenv`, not `rvm`) but doesn't solve the actual question, which was "How do I fix this or remove the rails executable to start a fresh install from scratch?"

Comment: I tried running `rvm install 2.6.5` but I get `Error running '__rvm_make -j4'`

Comment: Update: running `rvm install 2.5.0 --with-openssl-dir='brew --prefix openssl'` seems to have completed the installation ok.

Comment: This worked for me except I did rvm install 3.0.0 - thank you!